# Spinable turn dial: Calculate angle between two vectors, moving the reference line each time

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, popmotion

I have made the below spin dial, using [popmotion](https://popmotion.io/api/pointer/).

```js
const {
  listen,
  styler,
  pointer,
  value,
  transform,
  spring,
  inertia,
  calc
} = window.popmotion;
const { pipe } = transform;

const dial = document.querySelector(".dial");
const dialStyler = styler(dial);
const dialRotate = value(0, dialStyler.set('rotate'));

const dialRect = dial.getBoundingClientRect();
const dialY = dialRect.top + window.scrollY + (dialRect.height / 2);
const dialX = dialRect.left + window.scrollX + (dialRect.width / 2);
// console.log(dialX, dialY);

const pointA = {x: dialX, y: dialY};
// let pointB = {x: 0, y: 0};
// let angle = 0;
// let prevAngle = 90;
// Angle between origo and pointer
const pointerAngle = o => pointer( o ).pipe(v => {
  const pointB = {x: v.x, y: v.y};
  const angle = calc.angle(pointA, pointB) + 90;
  // console.log('pointA: ', pointA);
  // console.log('pointB: ', pointB);
  // console.log('angle: ', angle);
  // console.log('prevAngle: ', prevAngle);
  // console.log('angle - prevAngle: ', angle - prevAngle);
  return angle;
});

listen(dial, "mousedown touchstart").start(e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // prevAngle = angle;
  pointerAngle().start(dialRotate);
});

listen(document, "mouseup touchend").start(() => {
  dialRotate.stop();
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popmotion/dist/popmotion.global.min.js"></script>

<img class="dial" src="https://greensock.com/wp-content/uploads/custom/draggable/img/knob.png">
```

How can i get the dial to start at the same location each time i let go and re-click?

The way it works now, it moves to the cursor/finger position when clicking/touching. I would like it to instead start from the exact place it is currently at, and calculate the angle from there.

This is probably trigonometry related, but I have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: long time no see :p

Comment: if I understand well, you want each time to consider the current position as the new reference to calculate the new angle and move there?

Comment: Hey @TemaniAfif , long time no see. I have a few exciting updates for you, next time we speak. Yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Solved it, see below :) There is probably an easier way to do it, but it was the only approach I could wrap my head around.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution:

Normally, `atan2` (`angle` from `popmotion` in my case) calculates the angle between two points by assuming that a horizontal x-axis runs through the first point. It then calculates the angle between the x-axis and the vector running through the two points. After all, it does not make sense to talk about an angle between two *points*, an angle only exists between two *vectors* / *lines*.

In our case, we wanted the hypothetical x-axis to move to wherever we click/touch, so we start at 0 angle each time, before spinning the dial. The obvious solution was then to calculate *two* `atan2`, one from origin of the dial to the point when we first click, and one from origin of the dial to whatever point our pointer/finger moves to. Then we just subtract the first standstill `atan2` from the one that moves.

The above will ensure we always start at a 0 degree angle, when placing our pointer / finger down.

Finally, we simply add the old angle to the new, to start from wherever we previously left off.

**Below is the final code.**

PS: As a bonus effect, I added Inertia to the dial so it continues rotating at decreased speed until it stops, when we let it go:

```js
const {
  listen,
  styler,
  pointer,
  value,
  transform,
  spring,
  inertia,
  calc
} = window.popmotion;
const {
  pipe
} = transform;

const dial = document.querySelector(".dial");
const dialStyler = styler(dial);
const dialRotate = value(0, dialStyler.set('rotate'));

// Get origin of dial graphic
const dialRect = dial.getBoundingClientRect();
const dialY = dialRect.top + window.scrollY + (dialRect.height / 2);
const dialX = dialRect.left + window.scrollX + (dialRect.width / 2);

// Angle between origo and pointer
const pointA = {
  x: dialX,
  y: dialY
};
let startSet = false;
let startPoint = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
let combinedAngle = 0;
let prevAngle = 0;

const pointerAngle = o => pointer(o).pipe(v => {
  // Capture exact coordinate click/touch event happens
  // Used to calculate angle from that point and to where pointer is dragged
  // Also, capture last rotate position, to add to new angle
  // Ensures angle starts from where it previously stopped (not from 0 degrees)
  if (!startSet) {
    startPoint = {
      x: v.x,
      y: v.y
    };
    prevAngle = dialRotate.get();
    startSet = true;
  }

  const startAngle = calc.angle(pointA, startPoint) + 90;
  const pointB = {
    x: v.x,
    y: v.y
  };
  const mainAngle = calc.angle(pointA, pointB) + 90;
  const newAngle = mainAngle - startAngle;

  combinedAngle = newAngle + prevAngle;
  return combinedAngle;
});

listen(dial, "mousedown touchstart").start(e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  pointerAngle().start(dialRotate);
});

listen(document, "mouseup touchend").start(() => {
  startSet = false;
  const angle = dialRotate.get();
  inertia({
    velocity: dialRotate.getVelocity(),
    power: 0.8,
    from: angle,
  }).start(dialRotate);
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popmotion/dist/popmotion.global.min.js"></script>
<img class="dial" src="https://greensock.com/wp-content/uploads/custom/draggable/img/knob.png">
```

Comment: `Firefox 65.0.1 (64-bit) / Windows 10 Enterprise` Things are a bit odd when holding the cursor down as I go past the directly-up angle - the dial spins about 90 degrees opposite to the direction in which I'm dragging the dial

Comment: @scoots hmmm, that's weird. I only tested on `Chrome`. If you figure it out, let me know. I might have a chance to look at it later today.

Comment: @Scoots Interesting, my CodePen works in Firefox: https://codepen.io/magnusriga/pen/WmNOwO?editors=0010

Comment: Very strange, it now suddenly works in Firefox again, without changing anything. Perhaps it was related to the network connection somehow...

Comment: Working fine here now :)